# Sitemap does not get render correctly

Tags: google, sitemap, xml

I recently did some changes to my sitemap because i updated my website to support two languages but now i get an error when submitting the sitemap and i don't see where the problem is.

> ```
> Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file does not properly declare the namespace.
> ```

`````````
>     Examples
>     Line 5
>     Parent tag:
>     url
>     Tag:
>     link



    <urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/xhtml11_schema.html" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/xhtml11_schema.html http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd">
    <url>
    <loc>https://example.com/</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="el" href="https://example.com/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="el-GR" href="https://example.com/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/en"/>
    <lastmod>2020-02-25T12:41:35+00:00</lastmod>
    <priority>1.00</priority>
    </url>
 
           ````````

    
    </urlset>
`````````

***Update

Tried this method like the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions) says so

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Although when using `xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` converts the xml to plain text, changing `http` to `https` outputs the xml correctly and does the work but i have read you must use only `http` to avoid my issue, honestly this it too confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using `xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` looks like it's Google Chrome's issue that doesn't render the XHTML correctly (if i did understand correctly), the sitemap works fine now even though it is not rendered correctly.

You can read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/10921150/why-is-google-chrome-rendering-this-xml-file-as-html?hl=en)